# CKEditor in React not showing image upload

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

This is my CKEditor component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const CKEditorComponent = ({ content, setContent }) => {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      name='content'
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={content}
      onReady={(editor) => {
        if (content) {
          editor.setData(content);
        }
      }}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const text = editor.getData();
        setContent(text);
        // setFormData({ ...formData, description: text });
      }}
      config={{
        plugins: ['Essentials', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Paragraph', 'Link', 'List', 'Table', 'TableToolbar'],
        link: {
          decorators: {
            addTargetToExternalLinks: {
              mode: 'manual',
              label: 'Open in a new tab',
              defaultValue: true,
              // callback: (url) => /^(https?:)?\/\//.test(url),
              attributes: {
                target: '_blank',
                // rel: 'noopener noreferrer',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        toolbar: {
          items: [
            'bold',
            'italic',
            '|',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'insertTable',
            '|',
            'link',
            '|',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            '|',
            'uploadImage',
          ],
          shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true,
        },
      }}
      style={{
        margin: '2px 0px',
        minHeight: '350px',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CKEditorComponent;
```

How do I show an image upload button? Inside toolbar items I can edit/add all other stuff (break points, dividers, headings...), but can't seem to find a way for images.

Versions: "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^27.1.0", "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2".